# Different ways of evaluating $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

My friend showed me this integral (and a neat way he evaluated it) and I am interested in seeing a few ways of evaluating it, especially if they are "often" used tricks.

I can't quite recall his way, but it had something to do with an identity for phase shifting sine or cosine, like noting that $\cos(x+\pi/2)=-\sin(x)$ we get:
$$ I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}dx=\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\frac{-\sin(x)}{-\sin(x)+\cos(x)}dx\\
$$
Except for as I have tried, my signs don't work out well. The end result was finding
$$ 2I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}dx\Rightarrow I=\pi/4
$$
Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: It seems better to make the change of variable $x \to \pi/2-x$.

Comment: @OlivierOloa oops right, I'll fix it. Have any other ideas for how to integrate the above?

Comment: Does this help you:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167409/evaluating-displaystyle-int-0-frac-pi2-frac-sqrt-sin-x-sqrt-s?rq=1

Comment: @OlivierOloa yes, thank you! I will try to use that for mine and provide an answer

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Also related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180744/compute-int-frac-sinx-sinx-cosx-mathrm-dx/318212#318212

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1787431/evaluating-int-0-frac-pi-2-frac-sqrt3-sin2-leftx-right-sqr/1787442#1787442

Comment: See also : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439851/evaluate-the-integral-int-frac-pi2-0-frac-sin3x-sin3x-cos3xdx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let

\begin{equation}
I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos x}{\sin x+\cos x}\ dx
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
J=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin x}{\sin x+\cos x}\ dx
\end{equation}

then

\begin{equation}
I+J=\frac{\pi}{2}\tag1
\end{equation}

and

\begin{align}
I-J&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos x-\sin x}{\sin x+\cos x}\ dx\\[10pt]
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sin x+\cos x}\ d(\sin x+\cos x)\\[10pt]
&=0\tag2
\end{align}

Hence, $$I=J=\frac\pi4$$by linear combinations $(1)$ and $(2)$.

Comment: You might also be interested in seeing [the general method](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1829193/346183)

Comment: I came back to this question, and you're answer, and the link you provided is really fantastic, and quite general

Answer (score 4):

$$\int_{0}^{a}{\frac{f(x)}{f(x)+f(a-x)}}dx=\frac{a}{2}$$
let $f(x)=\sin x$ and $a=\frac\pi2$

Comment: Is there a name for this formula? Where can I find more?

Comment: No there is not

Comment: @qbert The formula arises from another one: $\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{F}\left(x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x = \int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{F}\left(a - x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x$ which sometimes we say "by reflection in the mirror" especially by people that computes MonteCarlo integrals. By adding ( to the original one ) and dividing by two we usually arrives to an integrand which is somehow smooth which the MC-people like a lot because it can reduce computing time.

Answer (score 3):

You're integrating on $[0, \pi/2]$ so replacing $x$ by $\pi/2 -x$ we see that $$I=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin{x}}{\cos{x}+\sin{x}}dx.$$ Now sum this integral with the initial expression and notice that $2I=\pi/2$ hence...

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Substitute $2i\sin(x)=e^{ix}-e^{-ix}$ and $2\cos(x)=e^{ix}+e^{-ix}$

$$ I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{2\cos(x)}{2\sin(x)+2\cos(x)}dx=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{i}+e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}dx$$

Now substitute $u=e^{ix} \implies du = ie^{ix}dx=iudx$

$$ I=\int\frac{u+1/u}{\frac{u-1/u}{i}+u+1/u}\frac{du}{iu}$$

---

Alternative method:
$$ I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}dx=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\tan(x)+1}dx$$

Substitute: $u=\tan(x) \implies du=(1+\tan^2(x))dx=(1+u^2)dx$

$$ I=\int\frac{1}{u+1}\frac{du}{1+u^2}$$

Comment: Ah I love it when complex makes integration easy. Thanks!

Comment: Added second method.